# Node - pushing an object to an array replaces the first item

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

functions.js:

```
const fs = require("fs");


var items = [];
var addItem = (name, city) => {
    var item = {
        name,
        city
    };
    console.log(items)
    items.push(item)
    fs.writeFileSync("entries.json", JSON.stringify(items))
};
module.exports = {
    addItem
};
```

app.js:

```
const yargs = require("yargs");
const request = require("request");

const ext = require("./functions.js");

var argv = yargs
    .options({
        name:{
            demand:true,
            string:true,
            describe:"Enter your name.  "
        },
        city:{
            demand:true,
            string:true,
            describe:"Enter the city you live in.  "
        }
    })
    .help()
    .argv
var inputName = argv.name;
var inputCity = argv.city;

ext.addItem(inputName, inputCity);
```

What I am trying to do is push a new object into the array items everytime the other file app.js is run.  When I run the file (node app.js --title="testing" --city="Windsor") in the command prompt, I get the array with only one object and I find that it keeps replacing the first item of the array.  How do I get it so that when the app has run, it ADDS another object to the array instead of replacing another item in the array.

```
[{"name":"aasdasdsdasd","city":"sdasdassddaasdasdasdsdn"}]
```

Comment: Shouldn't functions.js be initialising `items` to whatever is in `entries.json` rather than always to an empty array?

Comment: You will have to first read what was in the file, parse it, then add an item that THAT array, then write that array out.  You can't incrementally add onto the end of a file that contains JSON - it won't be valid JSON if you do that.  As your code stands now, you are just creating a new array, adding one item to it and writing that as the entire contents of the file, thus it is no surprise that the array always just contains one item.  You are always overwriting what was previously in the array in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `items` array is initializing with an empty array...

I think you need to be reading it before pushing a new object into it, something like this (untested):

```
const fs = require("fs");

function addItem(name, city) {
    var item = {
        name,
        city
    };
    fs.readFileSync("entries.json", "utf8", function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var items = JSON.parse(data);
        items.push(item);
        fs.writeFileSync("entries.json", JSON.stringify(items))
     });
}
```

Or, you could load it with a `require` at the top:

```
const items = require('entries.json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Default value for the `options.flag` param passed to `fs.writeFileSync` is `w`. This option either `creates (if it does not exist) or truncates (if it exists)` (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback), hence you see only the latest item in the file. In order to preserve the previously written components, you need to append to the file. This could be done by passing `a` as `options.flag`.